# Loading Dialog in BackgroundWorker

Tags: c#, multithreading, backgroundworker

For numerous reasons i cannot run the main portion of the code in a background worker, i can instead run a Loading dialog in the background worker but need to close the dialog after the execution of the main code portion. I've implimented the following but I'm not sure how to forcefully close the background worker after the code execution:

```
    LoaderWorker = new BackgroundWorker();

    //Loading is the Form
    Loading Loader = new Loading("Daten Exportieren");

    LoaderWorker.DoWork += (s, args) =>
    {
    //Show Loading Dialog
    Loader.Show();
    };

    ExecuteMainTasks();

    //Here i need to stop the backgroundworker after the method above is complete.
```

Is there a solution to this with background worker or should i use a different approach to ensure i do not lock the UI thread for the loader. Remember...i cannot execute the main code in the backgroundworker so have to manage this somewhat backwards.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
Control.Invoke
Control.BeginInvoke
```

(Windows Forms)

or

```
Disopatcher.Invoke
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke
```

(WPF)

or

```
CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync
```

(WinRT )

Calling this from the background worker will execute the passed lambda / delegate in the UI thread. Simply perform progress / finished notifications this way from your background worker.

So, show your dialog in the UI thread, then start the background worker, from which you can use this way of executing code in the UI thread.

Just make sure that you synchronously stop the background worker when the user cacels / closes the dialog.

Comment: Thanks Yeoman but I'm using C#6 and can't find any reference to Dispatcher.BeginInvoke or associated assemblies. Do you by any chance have a quick example of how this is implimented? I'm just looking to run an animated gif in a form in a background worker then run a complex operation outisde of the backgroundworker and close the background worker afterwards...very backwards, but i have to do it this way.

Comment: Which UI framework are you using? Windows Forms, WPF, or WinRT?

Comment: I think, WinRT is now called Universal Windows Apps, btw.